# How to disable Markdown syntax in Pycharm for Jupyter?

Tags: pycharm, markdown, jupyter

I'm using PyCharm to write Jupyter, and I want to hide an error in markdown code space.
But it seems doesn't work to use markdown setting in Jupyter, I still got the error.

Markdown setting:

[image: markdown setting]

Error code:

[image: error code]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just choose Syntax and don't show the error.

[image: 1]